# How to disable NSButton focus outline

Tags: focus, nsbutton, outline

When my application launches, it has one button. This button has ended up with a very ugly blue outline. How can I disable this? (Code or Interface Builder solution welcome.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In interface builder click on the button and then in the right hand panel go to the Attributes inspector. At the bottom of the attributes panel there is a section called "View".
The first item in that section is "Focus Ring".
Change this value to 'None'.

Answer (score 3):

It's 2016 and this is how you do it programmatically in Swift 2.2:

```
view.focusRingType = .none
```